# Does exhaustion affect passive perception in 5e?

Tags: dnd-5e, skills

1 level of exhaustion affected ability checks, but does it have any implications for passive checks?

Comment: Related: "[How does dim light affect passive perception?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/97968)"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Yes, exhaustion would be a -5 to Passive Perception.

You have disadvantage on ability check (which includes Perception).

[The PHB states](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/phb/using-ability-scores#PassiveChecks):

> Here's how to determine a character's total for a passive check:
>
> 10 + all modifiers that normally apply to the check
>
> If the character has advantage on the check, add 5. For disadvantage, subtract 5.

Comment: Thank you. Should have RTFM but I was looking for the answer in the exhaustion section.

Comment: @timstermatic no worries, it happens to the best of us